# Performing a lot of SQlite queries in Xamarin.Android fails

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I'm working on an app that gets some data from a webservice. The program is written in C# with Xamarin Studio.

The app has a local SQLite database stored in a file. I have created a seperate Database class to simplify the inner workings of the database (such as opening and closing the connection, etc.). Here's a relevant snippet of this class:

```
public static SqliteConnection connect(){
            string documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            try {
                return new SqliteConnection (string.Format ("Data Source={0};Version=3;", documentPath + "Database.db"));
            } catch {
                Console.WriteLine ("New DB created!");
                SqliteConnection.CreateFile (documentPath + "Database.db");
                return new SqliteConnection (string.Format ("Data Source={0};Version=3;", documentPath + "Database.db"));
            }
        }

public static void doQuery(string query){
            //Console.WriteLine ("Performing no-return query: " + query);
            using(var conn = connect()){
                conn.Open ();
                using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand ()){
                    var trans = conn.BeginTransaction ();
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                    trans.Commit ();
                }
            }
        }

public static DataTable getQueryResult(string query){
    //Console.WriteLine ("Performing return query: " + query);
    using (var conn = connect()) {
        conn.Open ();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand ()) {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
            dt.Load (rdr);
            return dt;
        }
    }
   }
```

After performing approx. 1900 queries, I get this error:

```
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: Unable to open the database file
[mono] unable to open database file
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Reset (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement stmt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Step (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement stmt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader..ctor (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader:.ctor (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand,System.Data.CommandBehavior)
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteTransaction..ctor (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection connection, Boolean deferred
```

This error is thrown at the "var trans = conn.BeginTransaction ();" line inside the doQuery method.

I think it's something related to not disposing the objects, but since I'm using using() for the connections and commands, I don't see why...

I hope someone can help me!

DebboR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem! In a background class extending Application, I permanently keep my connection open. Now I don't get any errors when inserting a bunch of elements.

I hope this might also be of good use to someone else, as I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

DebboR

Comment: Thank you, @DebboR! I searched everywhere, and you are right, if I keep my connection open, I don't get this annoying error :)

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you tried explicitely closing the connection for each time you open it. But using a singleton pattern using locks would be better as long as there is no concurrency issue. I'm very new to Xamarin but there probably is no connection caching.